# Checking for buddypress from a theme

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, hook, wordpress

How can I check for buddypress from a theme? I've found this page for BP [Plugin development](http://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/checking-buddypress-is-active/)

but this action never gets loaded if I hook from a theme. Why does it not work?

P.S. I need call some BP's functions from a theme, like: Show "BP's Activity Stream" at specific places.

What I mean with "never gets loaded" is:

(File in subdirectory of theme, and included in functions.php)

```
function sometestfunction() {
  exit();
}

add_action ('bp_include', 'sometestfunction');
```

This must make wordpress show a blank page, won't ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple check if function 'bp_is_active' is defined:

```
if ( function_exists('bp_is_active') ) {
  // do something here...
}
```

see shanebp answer and comments.

Answer (score 1):

> this action never gets loaded

You mean never gets called? 
Not sure why that would be, since you don't provide any code. 
But it's meant for loading plugins.

If BP is installed, it is loaded by the time theme templates are parsed.

Have you tried calling BP functions in your theme? 
I've never had a problem doing that.

Put your function(s) in one of these places:

- a plugin
- theme/functions.php
- bp-custom.php

http://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/bp-custom-php/

If your code will be used on installs you don't control, you should check for a BuddyPress component:

```
if( bp_is_active( 'activity' ) {
```

http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/bp-is-active/

Comment: updated question. why don't directly call BP's functions ?! because if is the theme active and buddypress not, this will generate errors (calling to undefined functions...)

Comment: Your 'sometestfunction' will work in bp-custom.php. It won't work in theme/functions.php because it's too late, bp_include has already run.  If you're calling BP functions and getting 'undefined' errors, then you're doing something wrong and should provide the code.

Comment: so if, theme/functions.php it's too late, a simple `function_exists('bp_is_active')` will work... correct ?!

Comment: It should. Did you try it?